# Snowflake Javascript Procedure Truncate Table not effective

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I spent most of this week writing out some Javascript stored procedure in Snowflake to handle a few things. But I can't for the life of me figure out why Truncate Table doesn't work.

```
    try {

        var get_tables = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'DATABASE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC;"
        var tableStmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: get_tables} );
        var rs = tableStmt.execute();

        while (rs.next()) {

            var table = rs.getColumnValue(1);

            var truncateTable = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE.SCHEMA." + table
            var truncateStmt = snowflake.createStatment( {sqlText: truncateTable} );
            var truncateEx = truncateStmt.execute();
      }
   }
```

This pattern of creating queries is in their documentation and seems to work for every other query I've put together. But it fails for this one and I don't get a syntax error or anything. I've left out the catch and stuff because this is the only relevant part.

I have additionally tried

```
var truncateTable = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE.SCHEMA." + table + ";"
```

I have tested this specific query against tables in a normal SQL query in Snowflake and confirmed that it works.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
 create or replace procedure util_db.public.truncate_table("table_name" varchar,"truncate" boolean)
returns string
language javascript
strict
execute as owner
as
$$
var sql_command = "Truncate table " + table_name ;
try {
    if (truncate){
        snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );
        return "Succeeded.";   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
    }
catch (err)  {
    throw(err);
   // return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
$$
;
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  This answer would be better if you added some information about _why_ it would work.

Comment: Hi Jake, I tested & verified it works. Seeing as they only have a snippet of code i'm not sure what the have missing. For example: 'Execute as Owner' if they don't have that, they may not have the permissions to do a truncate table.  details on that here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since you the SQL executes inside a try block, it won't display errors. Maybe you're handling that in a catch, but it's not shown.

If you comment out the try block, it should display the error when run. Maybe it's a permissions issue. Stored procedures can run with caller rights or owner rights. If the caller does not have the privilege to read from INFORMATION_SCHEMA or truncate the tables in the list, it will error out. You can call using owner's rights if that makes sense in the situation.

What happens when you run it like this?

```
    //try {

        var get_tables = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'DATABASE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC;"
        var tableStmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: get_tables} );
        var rs = tableStmt.execute();

        while (rs.next()) {

            var table = rs.getColumnValue(1);

            var truncateTable = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE.SCHEMA." + table
            var truncateStmt = snowflake.createStatment( {sqlText: truncateTable} );
            var truncateEx = truncateStmt.execute();
      }
   //}
```

Comment: I would have to disagree that query definitely returns the list of tables for snowflake. SCHEMA and DATABASE are just placeholder values I used to not use the real names of my database and schema.

Comment: Okay. I thought you were passing them in as variables. I'll edit.

Comment: What do you see in the Query History tab of the Snowflake web UI for this query execution?